# Raster to TIN tool missed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, tin

In the conversion tool there is not raster to tin and tin to raster tool. Also searching 'raster to tin' , I can find the name of tool, but it doenst work.

[image]

https://ibb.co/hRrNHyj

Comment: Do you have 3D Analyst?

Comment: yes https://ibb.co/N7N1zZJ

Comment: *Please* never just say *but it didn't work*, that will attract downvotes and close votes.  Instead can you edit your question and say *what actually did happen*. Was there an application/software crash, was there an error message (if so what was the complete error message as text, not screenshot), did the program run but produce incorrect/unexpected results (if so what were they)?

Answer (score 1):

You are searching in the wrong location. Raster to TIN and TIN to Raster tools are located under the conversion tools of 3D Analyst: `ArcToolbox -> 3D Analyst Tools -> Conversion`, not under the `ArcToolbox -> Conversion`:

[image]

It works only if you have 3D Analyst extension: [Raster To TIN](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/raster-to-tin.htm).

Comment: Mean 'id'?. I have also 3d analyst extension as you can see from link.   https://ibb.co/N7N1zZJ

Comment: @Promise89 it was typos error. it means `if`